# check reference class type at compile time

Tags: java

If I have some type declarations like:

```
JCheckBoxMenuItem t1;
JRadioButtonMenuItem t2;
```

and then a method like

```
addItem(JMenuItem i)
{
}
```

can I know if `i` is a `JCheckBoxMenuItem` or a `JRadioButtonMenuItem` type without having
an instance of them when I call it with `addItem(t1)` or `addItem(t2)` ???

Comment: Why do you want to avoid the instance of?

Comment: Are you saying that `t1` or `t2` are `null` and you want to check in `addItem` which type `i` is? It's impossible, since `null` does not belong to a type.

Answer (score 1):

If you need different behaviour based on the type of the object, don't use the same method. Make different methods, accepting different argument types.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can always call `t1.getClass()`, whhich will give you the effective class of the input object.

Comment: which doesn't much differ from `instanceof`

Comment: You can't use getClass and instanceOf bacause t1 and t2 aren't referencing an object and I want a check a compile time while both make a check at run-time